# php regex to search array key and return value

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to search in an array and then return the value of that key.

for example: 
I want to get the value of the `var1` key.

my config

```
<?php

return [
    'var1' => 'test1',
    'var2' => 'test2',
    'var3' => 'test3'
];

?>
```

then it should return `test1`

Comment: And how's that going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unorthodox question, but there's a straightforward enough answer here that does not require a regex, so I will present this instead.

Assume that your config file is called `config.php` and contains the code snippet that you provided in your example:

```
<?php

return [
    'var1' => 'test1',
    'var2' => 'test2',
    'var3' => 'test3',
];
```

You can actually assign the return value of `include` or `require` to a variable. For example, in another script (assuming you are in the same directory) you can do this:

```
<?php
// your config file...
$file = __DIR__ . '/config.php';

// ensure the file exists and is readable
if (!is_file($file) || !is_readable($file)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        sprintf('File %s does not exist or is not readable!', $file)
    );
}

// include file and assign to variable `$config`
// which now contains the returned array
$config = include $file;

echo 'original config:' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($config);

// update config key `var1`
$config['var1'] = 'UPDATED!';

echo 'updated config:' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($config);
```

This yields:

```
original config:
Array
(
    [var1] => test1
    [var2] => test2
    [var3] => test3
)
updated config:
Array
(
    [var1] => UPDATED!
    [var2] => test2
    [var3] => test3
)
```

I was originally a little surprised that you could use `return` outside of the context of a function/method, but it's perfectly valid. You learn something new every day... This use case is actually documented under the documentation for `include` - refer to [Example #5 include and the return statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for more details.

Please note, that if you are using `include` or `require` to pull in untrusted or external scripts, the usual security considerations apply. This is discussed in the documentation linked above.

Also, if your included file contains a syntax error, then you will probably get a `parse error` or similar, but I guess that's an obvious point!

**Edit**

Finally, I should point out that your question does not ask how to save the updated configuration back into the file, but you did leave a comment underneath that suggests that you want to do this also.

However, if you want to update and persist a configuration on file, I would definitely using a more malleable method to write/read this data to/from disk - perhaps `json_encode()` and `json_decode`, `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

Nevertheless, here's a naive solution in which you can write your updated config:

```
// ...

// file has to be writeable!
if (!is_writeable($file)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        sprintf('File %s is not writeable!', $file)
    );
}

file_put_contents($file, 
    sprintf('<?php return %s;', var_export($config, true)));
```

Further reading:

- [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)
- [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)
- [`is_writeable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writeable.php)
- [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but i need to write it back to the config file not outputting it

Comment: Indeed :) I did notice that you commented as much under your question, and I have updated my answer accordingly. Let me point out that your **question** itself does not specify this - I would suggest updating the question to include that requirement also.

Comment: Thanks that works, but is it possible to clean the file up, i mean its not really readable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: looks look something like this:

`<?php return array (
  'site' =>
  array (
    'url' => 'http://localhost',
    'name' => 'my site',
    'theme' => 'default',
    'language' => 'de',
    'maintenance' => false,
    ),
);`

Comment: Ah, I thought so. Okay, well three things: 1. if you want to add newlines between the opening `<?php` tag and the return statement, then you can format the string itself in [various ways](https://eval.in/484521). 2: if you are looking for the PHP >=5.4 bracket syntax for arrays then you're out of luck; `var_export()` does not do this. 3: I would personally prefer another persistence format here - here's an [example](https://eval.in/484524) with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`. This, I'd argue is more transparent, and you have a "language-agnostic" config format as a .json format file.

Comment: ok, one more question if its okey for you? how do i do that for a multidimensional array? like `'database' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '1234',
        'name' => 'dev'
    ],`

Comment: I switched now to json, and with your function it works like a charm! thank you so much!